# Always display a Key First with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat like:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in query_p[$index].tags">
```

I would like it so that if the key (k) is a certain string, say "foo", that string always appears first in the list. It seems the getter option or `orderBy` only works with arrays. Anyone have an example of how they might achieve this?

Comment: Your requirement is too specific. You are well off sorting the object initally (in the controller itself) before using it in the view's `ng-repeat` control

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have an unordered object, and you want it to have some kind of order.

To do that you need to create a function that returns some ordered object.

```
myApp.filter('promote_foo', function() {
    return function(object, comp) {
        console.log(object);
        console.log(comp);
        var ordered = [];
        for (var key in object) {
            var obj = {
                key: key,
                value: object[key]
            };
            if (key === comp)
                ordered.splice(0,0,obj);
            else
                ordered.push(obj);

        }
        console.log(ordered);
        return ordered;
    };
});
```

the function takes a parameter which will promote and object if the key matches it. Now I only call it in the controller directly, but you could use it just like any angular filter.

```
$scope.order = $filter('promote_foo')($scope.data, 'foo');
```

Also, you can play with the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KZgRe/).

Hope this helped!